# Roles not being correctly configured when migrating Enhanced EAR from WAS6.1 to WAS8

Tags: ear, websphere-6.1, websphere-8

I have an enhanced ear with ibm-application-bnd.xml defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<security-role name="myRole">
    <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
</security-role>
```

This myRoleis also defined in the WAR web.xml. The mapping between the role and ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS worked fine in WAS6.1, but in WAS8 after I deploy de EAR I can see in "Security role to user/group mapping" that myRole Special Subjects mapped as none. I have to manually map the special subjects to "All Authenticated...".

I've tried creating an ibm-application-bnd.xmi instead, but I'm currently not using RAD and have no idea if it's possible to do it in eclipse, since it has these generated ids like ApplicationBinding_1332889227228 that I don't know how to fill!

Answer (score 1):

Basically it may be a good idea to (1) deploy your EAR manually and set up all missing config data during this process as needed, and (2) have a look on the descriptor files generated by WAS8 afterwards. At least when moving from 4 to 5 and later on to 6 we used this "technique" to figure out how ready-to-go vendor-specific descriptors should look like. It may be necessary to strip off all pre-prepared vender-specific descriptors before executing this step.

2 Additional hints:

(a) WAS8 documentation says that WAS8 supports all previous J(2)EE standards, but generally XMI files are deprecated and should be replaced by XML files. But the "id problem" remains, since WAS8 also refers from vendor-specific files to standards compliant files by element IDs used in URL-like references. Thus any deployment of un-prepared EARs will create IDs inside the Java EE standard descriptors.

(b) It may be useful to do some research about the "new" name of your special subject: It looks like this name has simply changed from 6.1 to 8.x. For this purpose you also should take a closer look at the generated descriptor files after a successful manual EAR deployment.